# Using Jenkins' Publish over SSH plugin, how to stop a job execution and throw an error if 0 files had been transferred?

Tags: jenkins, plugins, ssh, publish

By default the build status remains SUCCESS if 0 files had been transferred by this plugin.

The "Fail the build if an error occurs" setting doesn't help as it works only if build status is UNSTABLE.

Comment: May be check if the file is available/updated on destination and if not, return a non-zero?

Comment: Any ideas how to do this inside jenkins job?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the destination file is updated or not, or if destination exists (in case if the file is new on SSH server)
Now, you can do this in "Publish Over SSH" plugin. There is a section to execute the commands on server through SSH.

[image]

Once file transfer is complete, do a check for required files. If required files are still not present, have a non-zero exit.

Make sure you tick the box "Fail the build if an error occurs".

Comment: About existence/non-existence everything is pretty obvious, but what can we do with checking file's update? "Exec command" executes only after the file transferring, and it's not possible to save previous state of file (using stat -c or smth). Ofc we can create 2 transfer sets in this build step, save previous state of file into a variable in the 1st one and perform transfer in the 2nd, but this variable will not be available in the separate transfer set (in this case in the 2nd one).

Comment: This may not be the solution for what you are asking, but may I know why is there any possibility of 0 files being transfered?
Is it because "source files" is null? or Remote is not reachable?

In 1st case, you can add a pre-check to fail the job even before starting "Publish Over SSH" in case source is 0.
In 2nd case, SCP itself will fail